# Is there a need for the nat table INPUT chain?

Tags: iptables, firewall

The [iptables man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) suggests the following standard tables and chains:

```
                raw     mangle  nat     filter
PREROUTING       X       X       X       
INPUT                    X       X       X
FORWARD                  X               X
OUTPUT           X       X       X       X
POSTROUTING              X       X
```

But the diagram in the [iptables Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) does not indicate the nat INPUT chain is used. I know the diagram is a simplification, simply because they for instance intentionally omit the security table. This might be a pedantic question as I try to teach myself firewalls, but the answer could be interesting.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: fix *nat/INPUT* order.

The [schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) didn't include [*nat/INPUT*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.c#L56) initially, but I incorrectly wrote that int was before *filter/INPUT*, and this schematic got (incorrectly) updated later with this chain between *mangle/INPUT* and *filter/INPUT* which turns out to be wrong.

*nat/INPUT* hooks after *filter/INPUT*.

As the *nat* type is special and is linked with *conntrack*, it also turns out that *nftables*'s priority doesn't even depend on the hook priority which for *nat* affects only priorities between multiple chains within the same *nat* hook. Using *nftables* instead of *iptables* can't alter this by changing the priority to a value lower than filter/INPUT's 0 or mangle/INPUT's -150: it always hooks at exactly 100. (Same behavior with nat/PREROUTING: it always hooks at exactly -100 for PREROUTING even if giving a chain priority of -199). All this can be tested using *iptables*' `-j TRACE` or *nftables*' `meta nftrace set 1` features and looking at the resulting order of traversed chains.  Tests made on kernel 5.13.x, specific behavior about this might change in the future. *iptables* not even being able to change these priorities doesn't have a choice anywhere anyway.

As [@Andrew Bate](https://serverfault.com/users/151385/andrew-bate) wrote, the correct schematic giving the correct order can be found [there](https://stuffphilwrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/FW-IDS-iptables-Flowchart-v2019-04-30-1.png) with currently this:

> [image: schematic]

that said, about the question...

---

*nat/PREROUTING* will apply before the initial routing decision, for *all* cases (routed, or for local endpoint traffic), *nat/INPUT*  will happen after the initial routing decision, *only* if traffic is deemed local.

The way it's implemented in relation to routing and connection tracking, before routing, with *nat/PREROUTING*, you're allowed to change what will affect routing: the destination (`-j DNAT`), but not the origin. After routing, with *nat/INPUT*, that's the opposite: you can't change the destination, but you can change the origin (`-j SNAT`).

You have a certain inverted symmetry with *nat/OUTPUT* (which is on the schematic) and *nat/POSTROUTING*: *nat/OUTPUT* is only for locally initiated traffic and can alter routing decision, like in *nat/PREROUTING*, thus can alter destination (with `-j DNAT`), second is for all traffic, routed or locally initiated, after any routing decision was already done (and can change source like *nat/INPUT* with `-j SNAT`).

To answer the question, *nat/INPUT* didn't exist until it was needed. It was specifically created to handle new emerging cases avoiding requiring namespaces but using [conntrack zones](https://lwn.net/Articles/370152/) instead. [It appeared in 2010](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit?id=c68cd6cc21eb329c47ff020ff7412bf58176984e). This link includes usage examples having motivated its creation, but it's quite difficult to grasp since it uses conntrack zones (which allow to separate totally identical flows (same 5-tuple protocol,saddr,sport,daddr,dport) into different conntrack entries by adding a zone tag on them. For example for special policy routed traffics, one arriving from *eth0* going to *eth2*, the other arriving from *eth1* going to *eth3*, or as in the first link to loop back traffic and track/nat it separately).

Comment: I don't think that `nat/INPUT` is between `mangle/INPUT` and `filter/INPUT`. `nat/INPUT` must be after `filter/INPUT` which is after `mangle/INPUT`. The source you linked for [nat/INPUT](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.c#L56) shows `nat/INPUT` has priority `NF_IP_PRI_NAT_SRC` which is [defined here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/uapi/linux/netfilter_ipv4.h#L41) as 100. `NF_IP_PRI_FILTER` is 0 (priority of `filter/INPUT`) and `NF_IP_PRI_MANGLE` is -150 (priority of `mangle/INPUT`). Chains are processed in order of priority

Comment: The schematic you linked to was updated on 2020-12-04 (after this answer was posted) to add the `nat/INPUT` chain. However, it is showing `nat/INPUT` between `mangle/INPUT` and `filter/INPUT` which is incorrect (see my previous comment). [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture) and [this chart](https://stuffphilwrites.com/2014/09/iptables-processing-flowchart/) show the `nat/INPUT` chain in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks for upating your answer! I am trying to trace packets using nftables' `meta nftrace set 1` as suggested in your answer. I have tried ICMP and TCP SYN packets and the tracing shows that the `mangle/INPUT` and `filter/INPUT` chains are traversed but *not* `nat/INPUT`. What type of packets did you send in your tests, and how did you generate these packets (e.g. Scapy)? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBate If you are using a network namespace you need a dummy conntrack rule somewhere to get conntrack (and nat) to register. Somewhere have a `ct state new` (no need for a final statement). I admit it's not very clear to me why I need this while the nat chain should do it. I do all my tests with a few namespaces managed through `ip netns`, a few veth and a few bridges. Then ping and socat.

Comment: @A.B. I appreciate a nice graph - one picture for thousand words. But there is no nested graph of the computer box with some physical interfaces (eth0 ..), some virtual interfaces (br0, tap0 ..) and lo, of course. Which of them are connected to (Locally generated packet), which of them generate (Incomming packet), how are they joined with (Outgoing paket) or (Local processing). Is the rules completely ingnoring routing rules of ip route list? I do experiment with iptables (resp. nft) more than month, looking for correct config for my [VM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734131/)