# Iptable traversal with docker chains

Tags: iptables, docker, network-namespace

Using [this](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/c962.html) as a reference and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1008556/is-there-a-need-for-the-nat-table-input-chain/1008586#1008586) previous post, I attempted at creating a iptable packet processing flowchart when docker containers on the bridge network are considered. The flowchart is shown below

[image: flowchart]

I had omitted some of the tables to keep the flowchart more concise. For example, I understand that before the first routing decision, a packet technically also passes through `mangle` and `nat`.

However, I am unsure whether or not my understanding is correct. Is my flow chart correct or if I am missing any important ip tables?

One thing that I am still unclear is how to incorporate the scenario of a packet being sent from a container to another container on the same network. Is this considered the top right decision? Part of my confusion stems from the fact that of a test where I ping another docker container from one docker container.

```
$ watch -n 2 -d iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 120 packets, 7060 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   16  1344 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   16  1344 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   15  1260 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    84 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    1    84 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 151 packets, 23212 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:3001

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   16  1344 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   16  1344 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I send 8 packets (or 16 ping/ping-response pairs). But according to this result. Here only 1 packet is received by the `DOCKER` chain, while 15 is accepted by the 3rd rule on the `FORWARD` Chain. Why is this the case?

Thanks for any hints in understanding how packets traverse iptables with docker containers involved.